# jquery selector fails after upgrade to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I had the following line of javascipt to select tr's in a grid:

```
$('#gridtable tr:gt(0):[name!="blank"]').click(function () {
```

This worked well until I upgraded my version of jquery to the very latest, now this line generates this error:

*Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #gridtable tr:gt(0):[name!="blank"] jquery.min.js:2*

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: The second `:` in `tr:gt(0):[name!="blank"]` is incorrect... it should never have worked in the first place.

Comment: ... and if you want to exclude the first element that doesn't have `name=blank` attribute, selector should be `$('#gridtable tr[name!="blank"]:gt(0)') ` Order of selectors matter.

Comment: @undefined - You just made the same mistake. Lose the first colon!

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't assume, but that gt(0) is likely there because the first row is a header row. If you move that into a thead, then you can change your selector to '#gridtable tbody tr[name!="blank"]'

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra colon in your selector:

```
$('#gridtable tr:gt(0):[name!="blank"]')
//                    ^ Remove this
```

---

I'd advise you to use a real CSS selector instead, since it's *much* faster:

```
$('#gridtable tr[name!="blank"]:not(:first-child)')
```

Comment: The CSS (second) alternative you provided works great!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is strange why the previous version of jQuery was not raising the same error. You have problem in the selector. If you are looking for elements with `name != "blank"` inside `<tr>` elements (not first row), then use:

```
$("#gridtable tr:gt(0) [name!='blank']")
```

If `<tr>` elements should also have filter for `name != "blank"` then use:

```
$("#gridtable tr[name!='blank']:gt(0)")
```

So no colon `:` symbol required for [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/).

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two alternatives.  (Can you explain more).  I am trying to find rows greater than row 0, who also have a name not equal to "blank".

Comment: @Michelle Then the second selector is a way to go. The first one will search for elements with name not equal to "blank" inside the rows. **DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yyANR/

Comment: Neither one works like the old one...somethings not right.  But the CSS answer posted above works...

Comment: @Michelle I have updated the second example, you may check it out.

Comment: @VisioN - This selector is different than the OP's. If the first `tr` is `name=blank`, a different `tr` will be missing from the matched set: http://jsfiddle.net/MU6jC/

Comment: @JosephSilber Agree, it is different, and I assume your solution is absolutely correct. But the OP didn't use `:not(:first-child)` from the start, that's why I left it in my version.